# Swift - Updating UILabel Prevents Subviews from Changing

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, subview

I'm currently learning Swift with Stanford's iOS 11 course. One of the projects is a card game called "Set". For that project I have a subview called "cardView" inside the ViewController, where all of the cards on the field are displayed.
Inside that "cardView" I create a subview for each card.
The goal is to find 3 cards that make up a "set".
I also have a hint button, which shows me a possible solution by changing the color of 3 cards that make up a "set".
Everytime I tap on that hint button though my score will decrease.
This is my IBAction:

```
@IBAction private func hintButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    for subview in cardView.subviews {
        subview.layer.borderWidth = 0
    }
    game.hint()
    if !game.selectedCards.isEmpty {
        for index in game.indicesOfSelectedCards {
            cardView.subviews[index].layer.borderWidth = 4
            cardView.subviews[index].layer.cornerRadius = 8
            cardView.subviews[index].layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            print("cardView.subview[\(index)] changed borderColor.")
        }
        game.resetSelectedCards()
    } else {
        print("There are no sets on the field")
    }
    scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(game.score)"
}
```

For some reason if I change the text of the scoreLabel the subviews/cards that make up a "set" won't update and I can't see any change of the border. 
If I delete this line
`scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(game.score)"` though I can see the change of the subviews but then I don't see my updated score...
I also worked with breakpoints to figure out on which line this bug occurs and I found out that my subviews won't change as long as I have that line in there where I change the text of the scoreLabel even though that line is at the end of that method.
I just can't figure out how to update the score + show a possible solution at the same time. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's the code in game.resetSelectedCards()

Comment: So with game.hint() I basically copy three cards from an array called "cardsOnTheField" that form a "set" to an array called "selectedCards" and I put their indices in another array called "indicesOfSelectedCards". 
With game.resetSelectedCards I only remove everything inside "selectedCards" and "indicesOfSelectedCards".